# Connecting Superset to DB2

Tags: db2, apache-superset

After installing the driver ibm_db_sa, I was able to add DB2 driver and connect to my DB2 database. however I am facing issue in retrieving the table data and getting the below error :

```
2023-05-11 06:12:20,669:DEBUG:superset.stats_logger:[stats_logger] (incr) DatabaseRestApi.table_metadata.success
2023-05-11 06:12:20,669:DEBUG:superset.stats_logger:[stats_logger] (incr) DatabaseRestApi.table_metadata.error
2023-05-11 06:12:20,675:ERROR:flask_appbuilder.api:Object of type LegacyRow is not JSON serializable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/__init__.py", line 110, in wraps
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chihaoui/Desktop/superset/superset/views/base_api.py", line 121, in wraps
    raise ex
  File "/home/chihaoui/Desktop/superset/superset/views/base_api.py", line 115, in wraps
    duration, response = time_function(f, self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chihaoui/Desktop/superset/superset/utils/core.py", line 1587, in time_function
    response = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chihaoui/Desktop/superset/superset/utils/log.py", line 266, in wrapper
    value = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chihaoui/Desktop/superset/superset/databases/api.py", line 697, in table_metadata
    return self.response(200, **table_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/__init__.py", line 769, in response
    _ret_json = jsonify(kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 302, in jsonify
    f"{dumps(data, indent=indent, separators=separators)}\n",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 132, in dumps
    return _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 51, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type LegacyRow is not JSON serializable
192.168.240.1 - - [11/May/2023 06:12:20] "GET /api/v1/database/4/table/COLLECTION/MAXIMO%20%20/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2023-05-11 06:12:20,704:INFO:werkzeug:192.168.240.1 - - [11/May/2023 06:12:20] "GET /api/v1/database/4/table/COLLECTION/MAXIMO%20%20/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

[Click here to view the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkJw8.png)

> The below block of code is triggering this issue :
>
> ```
>   self.incr_stats("init", self.table_metadata.__name__)
>         try:
>             table_info = get_table_metadata(database, table_name, schema_name)
>         except SQLAlchemyError as ex:
>             self.incr_stats("error", self.table_metadata.__name__)
>             return self.response_422(error_msg_from_exception(ex))
>         except SupersetException as ex:
>             return self.response(ex.status, message=ex.message)
>         
>         self.incr_stats("success", self.table_metadata.__name__)
>         return self.response(200, **table_info)
> ```

Comment: I suggest you create a ticket on the superset issues github site , at https://github.com/apache/superset/issues  , you might need to give more details on their template when you create the issue.